# how to make a three js css3d panorama without a cubemap

Tags: javascript, css, three.js, panoramas

I haven't been able to find an example on how to do this. I've achieved what I want to accomplish using WebGL, and now I'm making a CSS3D fallback. The method I used in WebGL won't work because CSS3D can't handle meshes.

So is there a way to render a panorama in CSS3D using a single panoramic image instead of a cubemap?

Answer (score 0):

Try skydome instead, it do not need more than one image. But still must be processed for a cube wrapping.
http://www.ianww.com/2014/02/17/making-a-skydome-in-three-dot-js/

Comment: unfortunately this won't render without webgl, and the purpose of this task is to create a fallback for those who don't support webgl, but do support css3d.